# Bad Karma and Moksha

Tags: scripture, karma, moksha

Can a person who has done bad karma and not yet received its fruits, still achieve moksha? What do the scriptures say about it?

Comment: yes, gods grace can wash all sins and give moksha.Thats mentioned in our scriptures!Even prayaschitta can wash the sins if done i proper way.

Comment: If one surrenders to Paramatma, yes all karmas are washed away.

Comment: @Partha Please can you give reference to scriptures?

Comment: @AkshayS Please can you give reference to scriptures?

Comment: @user5155835 https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30202/according-to-hindu-scriptures-what-are-some-of-the-great-sins-that-god-never-fo/30203#30203

Answer (score 1):

Moksha is obtained when one gets rid of all sins. Many scriptures say about getting freed from sins. I am quoting a few.

1. Srimad-Bhagavatam(11/3) says

> kaler doshanidhe rajan asti hi eko mahan gunah/kirtanaad eva krishnasya muktasangah param vrajet

meaning:The age of Kali, the abode of vices has one great quality. One by chanting the name of Krishna is freed from all bondages (sins) and get liberated.

Padma-Purana (Uttara-Khanda) says

> svapacho vrijinam kartum na hi saknoti yatnatah/taavad hartum mune javat krishna-naamaanukirtanam

meaning: Even a chandala can not perform such sin which can not be washed by chanting of krishna-naama.

Vrihat-Naradiya-Puran says:

> kirtanaadeva krishnasya vishnor amitatejasah/duritaani viliyante tamaansiva dinodaye

meaning: Chanting the name of Krishna, Vushnu whise vigour is infinite, one is freed from sins like sun kills darkness.

Vaishvanara-samhita says

> krishna eti nityam yo bruyat bhakyaa ratridivam narah/mahapaatakkotibho muktah puto bhabet tu sah//

meaning: Who chants the name of Krishna day and night is freed from crores of grave sins and becomes pure.

> tan naasti kamajam loke vakjam manasam eva va/yan na kshapayate paapam kalau govindakirtanam

meaning : There is not  a single physical verbal or mental sin that can not be washed off by chanting Krishna's name.

Similarly, chanting of names of Durga, Shiva, Rama also removes all sins according to different Tantras.

Padmapuran (Uttarakhanda, chapter 98) says

> harinaama-rato bhutva sarva-karma parityajet/sa sarvapaapan mukto yah padmam hitva udakam yatha//

neaning : He who is engaged in chanting of Harinaama rejecting all other activities is freed from all sins as lotus is free of water.

In Gita (18/66) Sri Krishna says

> O Arjun, leaving all other scriptural duties, surrender to me alone. I will remove all your sins, dont you lament.

Reference: Sri Sri Nama-Mahima-Amrita, Sitaramda Omkarnath, Mahamilan Math, Vol 8 (The entire book contains innumerable quotations on this topic).

Comment: Is this true: "Moksha is obtained when one gets rid of all sins."? Or should it be that Moksha is attained when one has no physical desires left and only wants to be with Supreme soul?

Comment: Desires come from sin.no sin implies no desire

Comment: As Partha says, from impurities arise desires, when all karmas are washed, mind becomes still in the Atma.